# Android Splash screen with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I have introduced a splash screen before the first activity of my Android app. This splash screen uses an AsyncTask to download some information before the first activity starts. As this can take up to 5 seconds, I have a progress bar to show progress to the user. The AsyncTask is kicked off as expected, but the only way I could get the splash screen to display is by creating a separate Thread. If I don't use the separate Thread the splashscreen does not display. The app just shows a blank screen, the AsyncTask runs in the background and then the app transitions to the main activity.

So it functionally works, but I'd like to start the AsyncTask without spawning a separate Thread. What are my options?

The part of the code I want to remove is the following.

```
new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                startDownloadTask(); //kicks off the AsyncTask.
            };          
        }.start();
```

Here is my code.

**AppManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.drillexams.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.drillexams.android.WorkInProgressActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.drillexams.android.ExamListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EXAMSLIST" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.drillexams.android.SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.drillexams.android.ExamListActivity">
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.drillexams.android.ExamListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.drillexams.android.DrillQuestionActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.drillexams.android.ExamListActivity">
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.drillexams.android.ExamListActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:label="Android tests"
        android:targetPackage="com.drillexams.android" />

</manifest>
```

**activity_work_in_progress.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".WorkInProgressActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drillExamsLogoImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/drill_exams_logo_content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drill_exams_logo" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drillExamsLogoImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**WorkInProgressActivity.java**

```
package com.drillexams.android;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.drillexams.android.service.DrillExamsService;
import com.drillexams.android.sync.util.DownloadExamListHelper;
import com.drillexams.android.util.DrillExamsLogger;
import com.drillexams.model.Exam;

public class WorkInProgressActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    ProgressTask task = new ProgressTask();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DrillExamsLogger.start("WorkInProgressActivity.onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_in_progress);

        new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                startDownloadTask();
            };          
        }.start();

        DrillExamsLogger.end("WorkInProgressActivity.onCreate");
    }


    public void startDownloadTask() {  
        DrillExamsLogger.start("WorkInProgressActivity.startDownloadTask");
        try {
            task.execute(new URL(DrillExamsService.EXAM_URL));  
            task.get();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            DrillExamsLogger.e(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            DrillExamsLogger.e(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            DrillExamsLogger.e(e);
        }
        DrillExamsLogger.end("WorkInProgressActivity.startDownloadTask");          
    }  

    public void stopProgress() {  
        task.cancel(true);    
    }  

    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, List<Exam>> {     
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private String token;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.bringToFront();         

        }

        protected List<Exam> doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            List<Exam> examsList = null;
            DrillExamsLogger.start("DownloadExamList.doInBackground");
            int start=0;  
            for(int i=start;i<=100;i+=5){  
                try {  
                    if(!isCancelled()){  
                        publishProgress(i);
                        progressBar.setProgress(i);
                        DrillExamsLogger.v("increment " + i);  
                        SystemClock.sleep(300);  
                    }  
                } catch (Exception e) {  
                    DrillExamsLogger.e(e);  
                }     
            }  
        return null;  
        }  


        protected void onPostExecute(List<Exam> params) {
            super.onPostExecute(params);
            DrillExamsLogger.start("WorkInProgressActivity.onPostExecute");
            Intent intent = new Intent(WorkInProgressActivity.this, ExamListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            DrillExamsLogger.end("WorkInProgressActivity.onPostExecute");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: just call startDownloadTask() directly after setContentView(), there is no need to start it from a separated Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you have to create the Thread is that you call

```
task.get();
```

This makes the AsyncTask run on UI thread, blocking until it completes.

So, simply remove the task.get():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DrillExamsLogger.start("WorkInProgressActivity.onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_in_progress);

    startDownloadTask();

    DrillExamsLogger.end("WorkInProgressActivity.onCreate");
}


public void startDownloadTask() {  
    DrillExamsLogger.start("WorkInProgressActivity.startDownloadTask");
    try {
        task.execute(new URL(DrillExamsService.EXAM_URL));  
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        DrillExamsLogger.e(e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        DrillExamsLogger.e(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        DrillExamsLogger.e(e);
    }
    DrillExamsLogger.end("WorkInProgressActivity.startDownloadTask");          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be the typical application for the proxy pattern? Your Proxy is showing the splash screen and updates the progress bar, until everything is loaded!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `progressBar.setProgress(i);` from within the AsyncTask background method - updating UI elements from threads different to their creation thread is not allowed and is probably throwing an exception.

Also, you're calling `publishProgress(i)`, but you haven't overridden the onProgressUpdate() method, so it's not going to have any effect.

Try overriding the onProgressUpdate() method and updating the progressBar from there:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
}
```

Comment: i have made the updates you have suggested and the progress bar is updating correctly. Any ideas on how can I get rid of the Thread I am forking in the onCreate() method?